# Issue using regex to split strings with a list of delimiters

Tags: python, regex

I am using this function to split a text in words and separators while preserving them

```
import re 

def split_text_in_words(phrase_text, separators=[" "]):
  separator_regex = """({0})""".format("""|""".join(separators))
  return [f for f in re.split(separator_regex,phrase_text) if len(f) > 0]
```

I am using this code like this:

```
>>> split_text_in_words('Mary & his family has a?nice.house at #157, at the beach? Of course! it is great. I owe her 40$ so I plan to pay my debt weekly at 3% interest :) "no comment"', separators=[' ', '\?', '\*', '\.', ',', ';', ':', "'", '"', '-', '\?', '!', '#', '\$', '%', '^', '&'])
['Mary', ' ', '&', ' ', 'his', ' ', 'family', ' ', 'has', ' ', 'a', '?', 'nice', '.', 'house', ' ', 'at', ' ', '#', '157', ',', ' ', 'at', ' ', 'the', ' ', 'beach', '?', ' ', 'Of', ' ', 'course', '!', ' ', 'it', ' ', 'is', ' ', 'great', '.', ' ', 'I', ' ', 'owe', ' ', 'her', ' ', '40', '$', ' ', 'so', ' ', 'I', ' ', 'plan', ' ', 'to', ' ', 'pay', ' ', 'my', ' ', 'debt', ' ', 'weekly', ' ', 'at', ' ', '3', '%', ' ', 'interest', ' ', ':', ')', ' ', '"', 'no', ' ', 'comment', '"']
```

This looks good so far and is precisely what I want. However when adding parens on the list of separators and I happen to have the text starting with a parens, the splitting gears don't kick in:

```
>>> split_text_in_words('(as if it was not aware) Mary & his family has a?nice beach* house at #157, at the beach? Of course! it is great. I owe her 40$ so I plan to pay my debt weekly at 3% interest :) "no comment"', separators=[' ', '\?', '\*', '\.', ',', ';', ':', "'", '"', '-', '\?', '!', '#', '\$', '%', '^', '&', '\*', '\(', '\)'])
['(as', ' ', 'if', ' ', 'it', ' ', 'was', ' ', 'not', ' ', 'aware', ')', ' ', 'Mary', ' ', '&', ' ', 'his', ' ', 'family', ' ', 'has', ' ', 'a', '?', 'nice', ' ', 'beach', '*', ' ', 'house', ' ', 'at', ' ', '#', '157', ',', ' ', 'at', ' ', 'the', ' ', 'beach', '?', ' ', 'Of', ' ', 'course', '!', ' ', 'it', ' ', 'is', ' ', 'great', '.', ' ', 'I', ' ', 'owe', ' ', 'her', ' ', '40', '$', ' ', 'so', ' ', 'I', ' ', 'plan', ' ', 'to', ' ', 'pay', ' ', 'my', ' ', 'debt', ' ', 'weekly', ' ', 'at', ' ', '3', '%', ' ', 'interest', ' ', ':', ')', ' ', '"', 'no', ' ', 'comment', '"']
```

The first parens remains attached to the word. I can work around this issue by simply appending a space at beginning:

```
>>> split_text_in_words(' (as if it was not aware) Mary & his family has a?nice beach* house at #157, at the beach? Of course! it is great. I owe her 40$ so I plan to pay my debt weekly at 3% interest :) "no comment"', separators=[' ', '\?', '\*', '\.', ',', ';', ':', "'", '"', '-', '\?', '!', '#', '\$', '%', '^', '&', '\*', '\(', '\)'])
[' ', '(', 'as', ' ', 'if', ' ', 'it', ' ', 'was', ' ', 'not', ' ', 'aware', ')', ' ', 'Mary', ' ', '&', ' ', 'his', ' ', 'family', ' ', 'has', ' ', 'a', '?', 'nice', ' ', 'beach', '*', ' ', 'house', ' ', 'at', ' ', '#', '157', ',', ' ', 'at', ' ', 'the', ' ', 'beach', '?', ' ', 'Of', ' ', 'course', '!', ' ', 'it', ' ', 'is', ' ', 'great', '.', ' ', 'I', ' ', 'owe', ' ', 'her', ' ', '40', '$', ' ', 'so', ' ', 'I', ' ', 'plan', ' ', 'to', ' ', 'pay', ' ', 'my', ' ', 'debt', ' ', 'weekly', ' ', 'at', ' ', '3', '%', ' ', 'interest', ' ', ':', ')', ' ', '"', 'no', ' ', 'comment', '"']
```

But I'm concerned why this happening and if the strategy (hack, really) of adding a space at the beginning does not reassure me that it won't fail in some other more subtle case

Why is this happening, and would the hack/fix of appending a space at the beginning work in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the unescaped `^`. You should probably escape all punctuation characters you use with something like:

```
split_text_in_words(
    '(as if it was not aware) Mary & his family',
    separators=["\\" + c for c in " ?*.,;:'\"-!#$%^&()"]
)
```

Maybe, even do it in the function:

```
import re 

def split_text_in_words(phrase_text, separators=[" "]):
    inter = "|".join(
        re.sub(r"(^|[^\\])([^A-Za-z0-9])", r"\\\2", sep) for sep in separators
    )
    # Add the backslash if not already present for every non-alphanumeric
    # character.

    separator_regex = "({0})".format(inter)
    return [f for f in re.split(separator_regex, phrase_text) if len(f) > 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is use of unescaped `^` in your separator that becomes part of your splitting regex. `^` is a special regex meta-character that means start anchor.

You must escape it as this:

```
separators=[' ', '\?', '\*', '\.', ',', ';', ':', "'", '"', '-', '\?', '!', '#', '\$', '%', '\^', '&', '\*', '\(', '\)']
```

Answer (score 1):

`^` marks the beginning of the string so it must be escaped in the separator list: `'\^'`

A more comfortable and safer way would be to not escape the separators in the parameter but in the function instead:

```
separator_regex = """({0})""".format("""|""".join(map(re.escape, separators)))
```